# Does CLIPS 6.3 support Cyrillic Symbols?

Tags: clips

I try to use CLIPS and i will be glad if CLIPS is able to support Cyrillic symbols.

E.g. inside fact definition (fullName):

```
    (Member (tagName UUK_MMC) (fullName "Участок усреднения концентратов ОАО ММК")))
```

But in CLIPS GUI for Windows I got the following:

```
  (Member (tagName UUK_MMC) (fullName "Ð£Ñ‡Ð°ÑÑ‚Ð¾Ðº ÑƒÑÑ€ÐµÐ´Ð½ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ ÐºÐ¾Ð½Ñ†ÐµÐ½Ñ‚Ñ€Ð°Ñ‚Ð¾)
```

Is it possible to fix it? I tried loading *.clp files in ANSI/UTF8 encoding.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLIPS 6.3 supports UTF-8, but the CLIPS Windows GUI which is layered on top of CLIPS does not (it's based on very old Windows APIs). The CLIPS 6.4 Windows GUI supports UTF-8.